# Can you use php with React.js?

Tags: php, reactjs

I recently tried react.js and love how it makes single page apps and was wondering if you it can be used with php or would i need to use templates?

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP (or any backend). React doesn't care - like most JavaScript clients, it just wants to consume JSON (or XML, msgpack, etc.) from $SOMETHING.

You also don't *have* to use templates, but in some cases they can be used to build your React application's entry point, or if you want to use smaller pieces of React to start with (in an existing templated application). Alternatively, your PHP application might just serve JSON and let your web server (Apache, nginx, etc.) handle serving the React application.

Note: A framework/toolkit like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a popular choice for running a server with a REST API that spits out/consumes JSON. https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel appears to be a popular project (YMMV; I haven't used it myself) for getting things started with PHP + React.

Comment: "it just wants to consume JSON" --- react does not care of the transport format either. It can be XML or home grown binary serialisation format. I think the answer pushes too much on the JSON without a good reason.

Comment: I've amended my answer, however I wanted to keep it simple. Digesting formats other than JSON in a React JS (react-dom) based application is typically much slower and more unwieldy, and if the OP is asking about a greenfields project, setting them in the direction of JSON from day 1 is going to make life a lot easier.

Comment: "Digesting formats other than JSON in a React JS (react-dom) based application is typically much slower and more unwield" --- that's completely wrong. React JS is being fed with plain JS objects and does not care of where and how they were retrieved from. "setting them in the direction of JSON from day 1 is going to make life a lot easier." --- saying them React is built to consume JSON is even worse: they will think that's true.

Comment: Note that I said react-dom, not just React (reading into the OPs question). Are you suggesting that having your react-dom components digest (e.g.) msgpack from a HTTP API is no different from JSON? I'd disagree - the serialization into a POJO is a non-trivial cost and complexity. I should also mention that very little of this discussion is helpful to the OP - we're debating semantics.

Comment: react-dom does not care of data at all, it just accepts react components created with React and renders it to the passed DOM element.

Comment: I get what you mean: but I disagree that overloading the OP (who is clearly a beginner!) with the 1000+ different ways you can use React and digest data is helpful. If you can provide a clearer, more correct answer I'll happily delete mine.

Comment: Your *current* answer is fine. I only had concerns with the original revision that stated that React has something to do with JSON in particular.